# How to loop the printing of a subreport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Java application that fills a jasper report, with many subreports each containing up to 20 dynamic fields, to print a pdf file.

I need to print one of my subreports more than one time: I take this information from Java. How can I loop the printing phase of this subreport, passing to JasperReports' report just the number of repetitions that I need?

Practically I have an array of *n* object and I want to add to my main report *n* subreports, each done more or less like this:

[image: subreport_example].

I'm using Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The small sample and image can help to understand the task

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my question, hoping it is moreclear now

Comment: What type of datasource are you using? Are you using Detail band at master report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your suberport is inside the detail band, you could add multiple rows to your datasource. One for each "repetition" you want to have, so the subreport will be printed multiple times.